# How to use class and text attribute together in CSS selector in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, css-selectors

I'm working on [this](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?) site. There is a **Next** button. I want to click it using CSS selector only.

I'm using below code to get the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.RveJvd.snByac"))
```

`span.RveJvd.snByac` is also used for **Forgot email?** button so this one is getting clicked.

Is there a way to combine class and the text 'Next' attributes of Next button?

**Note :** I have to use only CSS selector.

Answer (score 2):

Css selectors do not allow selecting by inner text. To click that button with css you can just use:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierNext"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierNext span"))
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it worked. Can you tell me difference between above two lines of code? In which case addition of  tag (span) is helpful?

Comment: It depends on which element does actually have the action assigned. In other words which element actually represents a button.